# Use StaticResources in Class Library on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, winrt-xaml, staticresource

I want to create a class library for my Windows 8.1 project, which includes all the views for my app. So I've created the project, but Visual Studio told me that it is not possible to access the StaticResources.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock 
        Text="123" 
        Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
    <TextBlock" 
        Text="456" 
        Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

For example 'HeaderTextBlockStyle' was marked in blue and it told me that the resource 'HeaderTextBlockStyle' could not be found. So I can't see my page in the designer, because of the issue.

I can run my app without problems, but how can I get access to the StaticResources?

Comment: have you checked with the Textblock style 'HeaderTextBlockStyle' present in the  solution resources?

Comment: Yes. I have the StandardStyles.xaml within my ClassLibrary and there is the definition of HeaderTextBlockStyle.

Comment: What about other styles inside Standard.xaml ?

Comment: No StaticResource was found.

Comment: so it is a common problem , not for only text style, right ?

Comment: take your App.xaml & check whether the Standard.xaml resource registered inside Application.Resources.

Comment: Yes. It it a common problem. Because it is a Class Library I don't have a app.xaml file, so I can't register the standardstyles.xaml file.

Comment: Its better to add Views & Style resources in one project . So that you can use it easily. Try whether you can register tour Standard.xaml resources inside Page.Resources.

Comment: How can I add the file to the Page.Resources?

Comment: better to copy the resources which is needed for your page from the Standard.xaml & paste it under <Page.Resources> tag. Then you will get it in xaml

Comment: That can't be the solution. So I have no chance to change a global Resource, because I have to change it on every page.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.1 some things have changed, including the inclusion of the StandarStyles.xaml (it's no longer included explicitly). This guide is very helpful to make the transition: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/24/windows-8-to-windows-8-1-preview-starting-with-the-xaml-templates.aspx

For your specific problem I recommend you to try:

```
Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"
```